# Enabling tempcomp in Chrony

Tags: chrony

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi running Buster with an Adafruit Ultimate GPS hat. I'm trying to get Chrony to temperature compensate. I've modified the chrony.conf file to contain.

```
# Uncomment the following line to turn logging on.
log measurements refclocks statistics tempcomp tracking
tempcomp /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input 30 26000 0.0 0.000183 0.0
#tempcomp /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input 30 /var/log/chrony/tempcomp.log
```

The system is currently adding measurements to the tempcomp.log file every 30 seconds. However, if I enable the second (commented out) tempcomp line above, chrony dies on restart with the error

```
Sep  6 12:31:45 rpi-tick2 chronyd[24713]: chronyd version 3.4 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SIGND +ASYNCDNS +SECHASH +IPV6 -DEBUG)
Sep  6 12:31:45 rpi-tick2 chronyd[24713]: Frequency 23.662 +/- 0.165 ppm read from /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift
Sep  6 12:31:45 rpi-tick2 chronyd[24713]: Fatal error : Could not read tempcomp point from /var/log/chrony/tempcomp.log
Sep  6 12:31:45 rpi-tick2 chronyd[24711]: Could not read tempcomp point from /var/log/chrony/tempcomp.log
```

I believe this is due to the fact that the tempcomp.log files has entries like

```
===========================================
   Date (UTC) Time        Temp.       Comp.
===========================================
2021-09-06 17:40:47  5.2095e+04  4.7754e+00
2021-09-06 17:41:17  5.2582e+04  4.8645e+00
2021-09-06 17:41:47  5.2582e+04  4.8645e+00
2021-09-06 17:42:17  5.3069e+04  4.9536e+00
2021-09-06 17:42:47  5.2582e+04  4.8645e+00
```

Where chrony is expecting something like

```
20000 1.0
21000 0.64
22000 0.36
23000 0.16
24000 0.04
```

and sorted by temperature not sample time.

So it seems like I'm missing a step somewhere.

Also, once set up, is this a dynamic process where new datapoints are added as we go, or do we stop collecting data and just use the static table to compensate for temps?

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to manually create a chrony.tempcomp file, likely by analyzing the tempcomp.log file. They are separate files. Then specify the chrony.tempcomp file like this:
`tempcomp /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/temp2_input 30 /etc/chrony.tempcomp`